# Securing azure table storage connection string

Tags: azure-table-storage

How to secure an azure table connection string? It is not safe to store it inside code or in a config file. What is the best practice? Can I use some kind of certificate based authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encrypt the connection strings section of the config file. A certificate can be made using the Visual Studio Command Prompt which will be used as an encryption key. Once you have the cert, you can add it to your solution and encrypt the connection strings section. After that, upload the cert to Azure in the certificates tab. It's an ugly process, but it's not too bad. [This blog post should have all the details you need](http://www.heikniemi.net/hardcoded/2013/06/encrypting-connection-strings-in-windows-azure-web-applications/).