# Azure Table Storage Connection String Security

Tags: c#, security, ssl, encryption, azure-storage

First I want to say that I have searched Google and directly on StackOverflow for the answer to this question.  It appears that the [answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435452/securing-azure-table-storage-connection-string) is not what I am after because the deployment scenarios are different.  That user is deploying a web app, I am deploying a desktop app.

I have written a Desktop Application in C# that utilizes Azure Table Storage (ATS) extensively.  The communication between the desktop app and ATS is encrypted using https (part of the service provided by Azure).  This is the reason I connect directly to ATS rather than using my own service, the info exchanged is secured by SSL and I don't have to buy the cert.  Now I want to secure the connection string to ATS so that users cannot get this information.

All the scenarios I was able to find showed that the connection string was to be encrypted and then added onto Azure, however, those were for apps deployed to Azure and my app is deployed to the desktop.

My current solution is rather complicated but it does work.  I am currently using a combination of ATS and an MVC app to provide the connection string back to the client where it resides until the app is shutdown.  I expect that I will need to change this architecture so that the connection string is never stored but decrypted on demand.  This ATS/MVC exchange takes about 3/4 of a second right now and this hit is one I am prepared to accept because it happens only once at app startup.  I know that keeping the connection string in memory is not a good practice but until I can find a better solution.....

One thing to note, each connection string is different.  Every single company I deploy my software to gets their own ATS account in my azure subscription.  I do this to prevent ANY possibility of data contamination (one users data somehow being atached to the wrong user).  Because of this the damage of a breach is limited to the company where the security was compromised and not ALL the users across the entire App.

I am seeking solutions from the community on how to handle this situation.

Please note that I have read extensively on this topic before posting and the most promising article I have read is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b(VS.80).aspx) specifically the section entitled App.config Example.  It appears that in this method, I could use my current method for retrieving the connection string (it only happens once) and then from then on the connection string is encrypted locally and only decryptable by that machine.  This may be the answer but I do not assume that.

Comment: I assumed that you could create an ASP.NET Web API for providing APIs to communicate with ATS directly. You could wrapper the implementations of common operations to ATS in your Web API application. 
In this way, each connection string could be encrypted and stored into the App.config file or a database. Since the Web API is hosted on Azure, users couldn't get the connection string to ATS. Meanwhile, when a request sent to the Web API application, it should contain the identification for each company, which is used to retrieve the associated connection string for ATS.

Comment: Most certainly this is a solution, and likely it might even be the best one.  However, as my application currently stands it is communicating directly with ATS.  Thus, until I can get the time to write an extensive Web API to replace all the direct ATS work my app is doing, I still have this issue.  To all those out there who might have this issue I suggest the use of Encrypted Containers such as the ones found on this MSDN page. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tswxhw92(v=vs.110).aspx)